# Javascript: unable to understand the meaning of regex

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented this code from some site unfortunately i don not know the meaning of `if (/\D/g.test(this.value))`  , Please tell me

Complete code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.positionclass').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
   if (/\D/g.test(this.value))
    {
        // Filter non-digits from input value.
        this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
    }
    });
 });
```

what does it mean `/\D/g`?

Comment: what does it mean `/\D/g`?

Answer (score 5):

In a regex `\d` matches a digit, whereas `\D` matches anything that isn't a digit.

The "g" flag stands for "global", so you are effectively ensuring that every character of the string you are testing is not a digit.

If you didn't specify the "g" flag, then you would only be testing the regular expression against the first match in the string.

Answer (score 1):

`\D` matches any non digit character.

Answer (score 1):

The `\D` metacharacter is used to find a non-digit character and The `g` modifier is used to perform a global match.  So if used together, it does a search for non-digit characters in a string.

this might help you out: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_digit_non.asp

Answer (score 1):

`\d` - matches a decimal character.
`\D` - the opposite of `\d`, matches any non decimal numbers
`g` - The g modifier (javascript definition) is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).
`test` - The test() method tests for a match in a string.

For example:

```
var term = 'aaaa';
if (/\D/g.test(term)) {
    alert('yeah! non decimal found');
}
else {
    alert('baaa... only decimal found');
}
```

More examples:

- 'a1' - returns true because there is non decimal in the string
- '1' - returns false because there is only decimal there.

Answer (score 0):

The \D metacharacter is used to find a non-digit character and supported in all major browsers.

The g means Global, and causes the replace call to replace all matches, not just the first one.